# Return toString method, not returning what I want (Java)

Tags: java

I have a project where I am creating a BankAccount superclas with a SavingsAccount subclass. Everything is working fine but I am having trouble returning the string I specifically want.

Example: (Trimmed Down)

```
public class BankAccount {
   public static final double MONTHS_IN_YEAR = 12.0;

   private String myCustomerName;
   private double myAccountBalance;
   private double myInterestRate;
   protected int myMonthlyWithdrawCount;
   protected double myMonthlyServiceCharges;

   public BankAccount(final String theNameOfOwner, 
                      final double theInterestRate) {
      myCustomerName = theNameOfOwner;
      myAccountBalance = 0.0;
      myInterestRate = theInterestRate;
      myMonthlyWithdrawCount = 0;
      myMonthlyServiceCharges = 0.0;
   }

   public String toString() {
      String result = "";
      result += String.format("BankAccount[owner: %s, balance: %.2f,",
                               myCustomerName, myAccountBalance);
      result += String.format(" interest rate: %.2f,", myInterestRate);
      result += String.format("\n\t\t  ");
      result += String.format("number of withdrawals this month: %d,",
                               myMonthlyWithdrawCount);
      result += String.format(" service charges for this month: %.2f]",
                               myMonthlyServiceCharges);
      return result;         
   }
}
```

The driver class will use the toString method for BankAccount and it prints this:

```
BankAccount[owner: John Doe, balance: 0.00, interest rate: 0.05,
          number of withdrawals this month: 0, service charges for this                month: 0.00]
```

(Which is perfect for this superclass)

However, here comes the subclass SavingsAccount

```
public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount {
   public static final double SAVINGS_THRESHOLD = 25.0;

   private boolean myStatusIsActive;

   public SavingsAccount(final String theNameOfOwner, 
                         final double theInterestRate) {
      super(theNameOfOwner, theInterestRate);
      myStatusIsActive = false;
      if (super.getBalance() >= SAVINGS_THRESHOLD) {
         myStatusIsActive = true;
      }
   }

   public String toString() {
      String result = "";
      result += "SavingsAccount";
      result += super.toString();
      return result;
   }
}
```

When calling the toString method of SavingsAccount, it prints:

SavingsAccountBankAccount[owner: Dan Doe, balance: 0.00, interest rate: 0.05,
          number of withdrawals this month: 0, service charges for this month: 0.00]

(I don't want the `BankAccount` to be included, I just want it to print the "`SavingsAccount`" header then goes directly to `"[owner: Dan Doe,"`

I've tried having it return "`SavingsAccount`" first which it does correctly, but when calling super.toString(), it also ends up returning the `BankAccount` header which I don't want.

Any ideas on how I could fix this issue?

Comment: You're going to have to manually cut the front of the string off of `super.toString()`.

Comment: Don't call `super.toString()` if you don't want the super class's header

Comment: It would probably be more appropriate for the classes to have an `accountType` field which is automatically added to the string, then you won't need to overwrite it.

Answer (score 4):

A few options I can think of:

1. Replace "BankAccount" with "SavingsAccount" instead of just appending it:

   ```
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return super.toString().replaceFirst("BankAccount", "SavingsAccount");
   }
   ```
2. Move the details portion into its own method, and call it from each `toString()` with the appropriate header:

   ```
   // BankAccount.java
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "BankAccount" + getDetailsString();
   }

   protected String getDetailsString() {
       String result = String.format("[owner: %s, balance: %.2f,",
               myCustomerName, myAccountBalance);
       // ...
       return result;
   }

   // SavingsAccount.java
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "SavingsAccount" + getDetailsString();
   }
   ```
3. Get the runtime class name in the superclass so it doesn't need to be overridden altogether:

   ```
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       String result = String.format("%s[owner: %s, balance: %.2f,",
               getClass().getSimpleName(), myCustomerName, myAccountBalance);
       // ...
       return result;
   }
   ```

Comment: I was just about to try it, but does `getClass().getSimpleName()` return `SavingsAccount` in the subclass?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, it does.

Comment: Hey thanks so much! The first option worked perfectly! I like your 2nd solution as well but my teacher wants only the methods listed from the instructions

Comment: @bestgio The first solution is the simplest, but it's also a bit hacky. Personally, I prefer the third solution.

Comment: The 2nd option is technically the best one, but if your teacher doesn't allow extra methods (something that sounds quite ridiculous, btw), then the 3rd option is much better than the 1st one.

Comment: Agree that #2 is best.  When you say the teacher doesn't want extra methods, are you sure that applies to non-public methods?  It's often a good idea to add private methods--or `protected` in this case--to break code down into more readable chunks, and it's hard for me to believe your teacher would prohibit that.  (Or, to clarify, it's hard for me to believe a competent teacher would prohibit that; unfortunately, it's easy for me to believe that there are incompetent teachers out there.)

Comment: @ajb Yes, he docks points off when you add any additional methods because "I should be able to print the whole thing correctly without any additional methods but just toString(). Strict means strict :/

Comment: @bestgio Are you sure he wasn't talking about calling outside Java runtime methods?  The explanation your teacher gave seems illogical, which makes me wonder if there was a misunderstanding.